# Index.html instead of client stuff on server side

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

How can I get index.html for my app's client side?

The index page is defined in server.js like this

```
// load css styles
var css = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css"> ';
css = css + '<style type="text/css">' +require('fs').readFileSync('./style.css').toString() + '</style>'

http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  // send basic http headers to client
  res.writeHead(200, {
      "Content-Type": "text/html",
      "Transfer-Encoding": "chunked"
  });
  // setup simple html page:
  res.write("<html>\n<head>\n<title>Newsfeed</title>\n" +css +"</head>\n<body>");
```

But I want to get an index.html so I can use plain HTML for front-end.

Comment: This it too large to answer well on SO, but you need to write separate front and backends. I prefer using a REST API to tie the two together, but keeping them in separate projects (with a third, shared library).

Comment: You've already tagged this with [express](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/express) so doesn't that answer your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would explain the long.
Short answer is, you separate view, and use express middlewer for routing.

You must set view location:

```
app.set('views', __dirname + '/yourViewDirectory');
```

Put your index.html into `/views` folder

Then you can use `res.render` function:

```
res.render('index.html');
```

This is the base express server, which render `index.html` on `localhost:3000/`

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.set('views', __dirname + '/yourViewDirectory');
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.render('index.html');
});

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {
  var host = server.address().address;
  var port = server.address().port;

  console.log('Example app listening at http://%s:%s', host, port);
});
```